# Hiding chart lines with no value

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How can I hide the lines that go below value 1 so the chart doesn't look like the one below?. My chart shows a product sales over period of time. Some products don't have enought data which produces weirdly looking charts.
[image]

I have added `vAxis: { viewWindowMode: 'pretty' }`  and this is helping to some extent to make it "pretty" but it isn't enough.

I've tried with data view and I thought that was the solution but the view is hiding some extra rows. My code for view where I convert the 0 row to date and trying to limit the min and max values:

```
let view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataYear);
            view.setColumns([{
                calc: function(dataYear, row) {
                    return new Date(dataYear.getValue(row, 0));
                },
                label: dataYear.getColumnLabel(0),
                type: 'date'
            }, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
            view.setRows(view.getFilteredRows([{
                column: 1,
                minValue: 1,
                maxValue: 500
            }]));
```

I am a bit confused how view exactly works after many tries of tweaking up different columns and min/maxValues. In addition, I can target only 1 column at a time with the view? Bonus question: I would like also to hide the data points that are with 0 value (the one appearing on the x axis)
My chart code:

```
function chartYear(dataYear) {
            // Display the total number of products sold for each chart/period
            function getSum(dataYear, column) {
                var total = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < dataYear.getNumberOfRows(); i++)
                    total = total + dataYear.getValue(i, column);
                return total;
            }
            let name = document.querySelectorAll('.google-visualization-table-tr-sel td')[2].textContent;
            let interval = 1;
            let dataRange = dataYear.getColumnRange(9);
            let vTicks = [];
            for (var i = dataRange.min; i <= dataRange.max + interval; i = i + interval) {
                vTicks.push(i);
            };

            
            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                chartType: 'LineChart',
                containerId: 'chartYear',
                options: {
                    title: "6 months sales: " + name + "\nTotal: " + getSum(dataYear, 9),
                    curveType: "function",
                    pointsVisible: true,
                    pointSize: 5,
                    snapToData: true,
                    // pointBackgroundColor: '#FF0000',
                    titleTextStyle: {
                        fontName: 'Verdana',
                        fontSize: 13,
                        italic: true
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        viewWindowMode: 'pretty',
                        ticks: vTicks,
                        minValue: 1
                    },
                    hAxis: {
                        // minValue: 1,  // THROWS ERROR a.getTime() is not a function
                        // viewWindowMode: 'pretty',
                        slantedText: 1,
                        slantedTextAngle: 60
                    },
                    series: {
                        0: {
                            color: '#DC3912'
                        },
                        1: {
                            color: '#FF9900'
                        },
                        2: {
                            color: '#109618'
                        },
                        3: {
                            color: '#990099'
                        },
                        4: {
                            color: '#bbe9ff'
                        },
                        5: {
                            color: '#43459d'
                        },
                        6: {
                            color: '#C60AD3'
                        },
                        7: {
                            color: '#1c91c0'
                        },
                        8: {
                            color: '#3366CC'
                        },
                    }
                }
            });

            var dateSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
                'containerId': 'chartRangeFilter',
                'options': {
                    filterColumnLabel: 'Dato',
                    ui: {
                        chartType: 'LineChart',
                        chartOptions: {
                            snapToData: true,
                            height: 50,
                            chartArea: {
                                width: '80%'
                            },
                            series: {
                                0: {
                                    color: '#DC3912'
                                },
                                1: {
                                    color: '#FF9900'
                                },
                                2: {
                                    color: '#109618'
                                },
                                3: {
                                    color: '#990099'
                                },
                                4: {
                                    color: '#bbe9ff'
                                },
                                5: {
                                    color: '#43459d'
                                },
                                6: {
                                    color: '#C60AD3'
                                },
                                7: {
                                    color: '#1c91c0'
                                },
                                8: {
                                    color: '#3366CC'
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            var formatter_long = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
                pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
            });
            formatter_long.format(dataYear, 0);


            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'error', function(googleError) {
                google.visualization.errors.removeError(googleError.id);
            });
            
            let view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataYear);
            view.setColumns([{
                calc: function(dataYear, row) {
                    return new Date(dataYear.getValue(row, 0));
                },
                label: dataYear.getColumnLabel(0),
                type: 'date'
            }, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
            view.setRows(view.getFilteredRows([{
                column: 1,
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 500
            }]));

            

            var dashboard2 = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard2'));
            dashboard2.bind(dateSlider, chart);
            dashboard2.draw(view);


        }
```

The chart is drawn when the user clicks on a table row. I send the product id with ajax and get back data for this product. I can add the select handler if needed.

Comment: Are you sure this is a PHP question?!

Comment: please add sample data - see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: I've added some more code and edited the tags.

Comment: to prevent line from dipping below zero, remove this option --> `curveType: "function"`